# DS18B20 (thermometer): negative temperatures are read as 4 million degrees celsius

Tags: sensor, temperature, ds18b20, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I have five DS18B20 thermometers in my greenhouse connected to my `Raspberry Pi Model B Plus Rev 1.2`.

It is running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`.

Here you can see that the two thermometers which are ~15cm under the soil report 0.187°C and 0.875°C, which is reasonable as it has ~-5°C outside.

The three other sensors which are in the air report bogus values. This is due to some incompatibility with the software with my old pi, as

1. my pi zero with the exact same hardware (apart from being a zero instead of a b+, meaning: same little board with a 4.7kΩ resistor also driving multiple thermometers connected to the same gpio pins) and software setup can
   read negative degrees
2. it could read negative degrees just fine when I was still running minibian (on the b+) and not the latest version of raspbian (on the b+)

```
root@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices# for d in 28-*
> do
> pushd $d
> cat w1_slave
> popd
> done
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191a0f798a /sys/bus/w1/devices
b4 ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 b5 : crc=b5 YES
b4 ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 b5 t=4091250
/sys/bus/w1/devices
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191a40cfa1 /sys/bus/w1/devices
0e 00 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 71 : crc=71 YES
0e 00 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 71 t=875
/sys/bus/w1/devices
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191a42fc0d /sys/bus/w1/devices
03 00 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 0d : crc=0d YES
03 00 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 0d t=187
/sys/bus/w1/devices
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191a4d5e9c /sys/bus/w1/devices
9a ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 a4 : crc=a4 YES
9a ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 a4 t=4089625
/sys/bus/w1/devices
/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-01191a63a353 /sys/bus/w1/devices
ad ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 88 : crc=88 YES
ad ff 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 88 t=4090812
/sys/bus/w1/devices
```

Here is an image showing that the sensors are not broken, when holding them in my hand they report data as they get warm and go above 0°

[image: Here is an image showing that the sensors are not broken, when holding them in my hand they report data as they get warm and go above 0°C]

My questions:

1. Who do I have to send a bug report to?
2. Is there a workaround?
3. Can anyone that can read hex and knows their way around integers tell me how to extract the correct values out of the code block above?

Comment: Post the code that you are using.

Comment: @CoderMike you can see it at the top of the command block: ```root@raspberrypi:/sys/bus/w1/devices# for d in 28-*
> do
> pushd $d
> cat w1_slave
> popd
> done```

Comment: @CoderMike and then it says t=4090812 and that's 4 million degrees. When reading the "temperature" file instead of w1_slave it says the same

Comment: only the first two bytes appear to be related to the temperature, if it is temperature related .... first one could be FFB4, which is decimal -76 ... the others 000E = 14, 0003 = 3, FF9A = -102, FFAD = -83

Comment: Looks to me it's the same as https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4124 . A fix for that one is in the pipeline

Comment: @jsotola thanks for converting. That means the values can't be used then I guess :(

Comment: @Dirk oh my god, awesome. Thank you so much for the link! That finally brings clarity. Do you happen to know an estimate of how long it will take until I can run `apt update && apt upgrade -y` and get working thermometers? Is it hard to build my own kernel (extensions?) with the proposed patch?

Comment: @jsotola 99% of all questions asked regarding DS18B20 have been replied to with people saying "yOuR wIrInG iS iNcOrReCt" or "yOu aRe mIsSiNg a 4.7kΩ rEsiStOr". I meant that I have the same thermometers (also multiple) and resistor board to hopefully get a better answer. I will clarify the post. The pi zero is also running raspbian but I haven't installed updates in the last weeks. The model b was running minibian previously with the same thermometers where negative degrees worked.

Comment: @Dirk can you post the github issue link as answer so I can mark it as solution?

Comment: It's not 4 million Celsius off, it's 4096 (2^12). But the value given is otherwise good. Depends on what you do with temperatures later, but I just check if temperature is over 100C and then subtract 4096 if it is. Your example of 4090812 divided by 1000 and minus 4096 gives quite probable -5.188C

Comment: @JarosławKomar thank you very much, that was the secret formula I was looking for :) Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? My thermometers are now working fine and happily reporting.

Comment: @JarosławKomar the divide by 1000 sounds fishy ... formula is probably 4090812 ÷1024 - 4096

Comment: @jsotola No it's not - the kernel module gives temperature in 1/1000th of a Celsius. It always has - just look up any munin plugin. Or to remove any doubt - driver is at github https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-5.10.y/drivers/w1/slaves/w1_therm.c  Just find "t=", and then the relevant function temperature_from_RAM().

Comment: Your choice of 4.7K as the pull up is a general value used for 5V. Try changing it to about 3.3K and see if the other sensors come alive. You have a lot of capacitance to overcome.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in the latest updates: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/4124#issuecomment-775210673